# Outlook Appointment from Sharepoint Web Part

Tags: .net, sharepoint, outlook, web-parts, appointment

Is it possible to create an appointment in Outlook from a custom Sharepoint Web Part programmatically? VB.Net links or examples would be most helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here are some options:

**Dynamically generate ICS file**

The simplest way is to generate an [ICS (iCalendar)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ICalendar) file and present it for download. This won't automatically create the appointment but it's quite easy for the user to open and save into Outlook. There's a [great tutorial on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb655909.aspx) that shows how to do this.

**Use MAPI**

You can add Javascript or VBScript to your ASP.NET page and use MAPI to do this as well. [Here's the code](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/resources/officetips/apr05/tips0405.mspx) required. Again this won't automatically create the appointment. Other disadvantages are that the user will receive a security prompt, it will only work in IE, and IE's security settings need to be set to allow ActiveX scripting.

**Use Exchange**

If Outlook has been deployed into a corporate environment using Exchange, you have a few options: CDOEX (fairly obsolete), WebDAV (less obsolete), and Exchange Web Services (recommended). There is example code for [all of these here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc788131.aspx). Provided one of these options has been configured this is your best bet for a good user experience.